# how one function do various thing from one object to onother

Tags: c++

suppose that we have a class and in it we have a function(such as OnTouchListner) and any object from this class do various thing when this methode called.
any one know how can i resolve this problem.
real example from my question is job that MFC or any opreation system do.
below code is simple shape and summary  code of my project

```
namespace MyOS
{
    namespace GUI
    {
        class CControl
        {
            public :
            void OnTouchListner(void);  //my wrong solution is void(*OnTouchListner)(void);
        };
        class CButton : public CControl
        {
            public :
            ...
        };


    }
    namespace Core
    {
        class CKernel
        {
            private :
            EventListner();
        };

        class CForm
        {
            public :
            CLinkList<GUI::CControl> controls;
            ...
        };

    }
    namespace StandardDialoges
    {
        class CKeyPad : public Core::CForm
        {
            public :
            void Designer(void) {
                /*my wrong solution
                this->btnZ->OnTouchListner = &CKeyPad::btnZ_OnTouch_Listner;
                and call this in EventListner
                */
            }
            GUI::CButton btnZ;
            void btnZ_OnTouch_Listner(void)    {}
        };
    }
}
```

now my problem is call related function from controls when event listner detect a new event such as ontouch event.
i thought that function pointer is solution of this problem but now i that it is wrong way.
please help me to find solution of my problem.
with very thank.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Look at MFC or Qt source code on how this is implemented...

Comment: `Core::CForm` doesn't exist in your example, yet you try to inherit from it. There does apear to be a `GUI::Cform`, though... `CButton btnZ` should similarly probably be `GUI::Cbutton btnZ`. Over-use of namespacing can induce insanity...